# CCodeGenerator: auto-generated dll crashes

Tags: c-codegenerator

I am trying to use CCodeGenerator to generate a .dll library that I need to subsequently link in a custom C-code project.
However, I am stuck when using the following line of code:

```
funStructCompile = libData -> compileLibraryFunctions;
```

This line was given to me by the automatic CCodeGenerator output.
Also, I am unsure whether I properly or unproperly initialized the libData object.
This is what I did:

main.cpp

```
#include "WolframRTL.h"

__declspec(dllimport) int Initialize_MyFun(WolframLibraryData libData);

int main(){
    WolframLibraryData libData;
    int a = Initialize_MyFun(libData);
    return 0;
}
```

MauroLib.cpp

```
#include "math.h"
#include "WolframRTL.h"
#include <stdio.h>

static WolframCompileLibrary_Functions funStructCompile;

static mbool initialize = 1;

DLLEXPORT int Initialize_MyFun(WolframLibraryData libData) {
  if (initialize) {
    printf("1.\n");
    funStructCompile = libData -> compileLibraryFunctions;
    printf("2.\n");
    initialize = 0;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My compiling command sequence is:

```
> gcc -c main.cpp
> gcc MauroLib.cpp -c
> gcc -o MauroLib.dll -s -shared MauroLib.o
> gcc -o main.exe -s main.o -L. -lMauroLib -L"C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\13.2\SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows-x86-64" -lWolframRTL
```

gcc correctly compiles the project, however the .exe file crashes when executing the line funStructCompile = libData -> compileLibraryFunctions;
As a result I get the output of the first printf: "1.\n", but I do not get the output of the second printf "2.\n".

Can somebody help me with this?
Thank you

Comment: What exit code did you get? Try running `echo $?` or `%errorlevel%` on windows. Also try running a debugger like `gdb main.exe`, or since you're on windows windbg or vs.

Comment: In your `main` you need to allocate the `WolframLibraryData` like this `WolframLibraryData libData = WolframLibraryData_new(WolframLibraryVersion)` before you can use it. Then free it at the end with `WolframLibraryData_free(libData);`

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your comments! They were helpful in finding the bug!
In windows powershell (where I was running the exe) for some reason I was not getting the error code. So I tried to run the exe in classic shell and finally I could read the error codes.

Apparently my compiler was unable to find the wolfram libs (except WolframRTL). Putting all of them in the project root did the trick. I'll find a more elegant way to tell gcc where to look.

Hope this can be helpful to others!